# How to list all element attributes in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to know all possible attributes of an element in JS.

I did :

```
s = document.getElementById("idSvg");

r = s.attributes;

alert(r.length);

...
...
<svg width="450" height="250" id="idSvg">
...
</svg>
```

But the result is 3. Seems to be the number of attributes I use (width, height and id), but I would like to list ALL the possible attributes an SVG element may have.

Thanks for helping,
Rodg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, but better off looking it up on w3.org

```
(function() {
    var s = document.getElementById("idSvg");

    for (var key in s) {
        document.write(key + "<br />");
    }
})();
```

Comment: this seems not differ **attribute** from **property**, is there a better way to filter only **attribute** out?

Comment: all are treated as properties, you can make distinction however if it is local or inherited property, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/5CGNR/

Comment: Faster : `console.dir(document.getElementById("idSvg"));`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, as JS have no clue whatsoever about DTD format. You need to look at the tag specification (taking into account the proper doctype that tag will be used in).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html

> baseProfile class contentScriptType
>   contentStyleType
>   externalResourcesRequired height id
>   onabort onactivate onclick onerror
>   onfocusin onfocusout onload
>   onmousedown onmousemove onmouseout
>   onmouseover onmouseup onresize
>   onscroll onunload onzoom
>   preserveAspectRatio requiredExtensions
>   requiredFeatures style systemLanguage
>   version viewBox width xml:base
>   xml:lang xml:space x y zoomAndPan