# How to get all possible valid attributes on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, attributes

Please note that `.attributes` only gets the current attributes, which is not what this question is about.

I want a way to get ***all*** the attributes of a DOM element. Not just the ones that are on it now, but the ones that are possible in the future too.

The specific use case is to find the potential attributes in an `SVGElement` that aren't in an `HTMLElement` - there's a list on MDN ([SVG Attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)), but, for obvious reasons, hardcoding is not a good idea.

My initial thought was to iterate through the prototype chain of an instance of each and compare the two lists (with basic filtering for event handlers), but this doesn't actually give the potential svg attributes.

**EDIT**

- IMPORTANT NOTE - pasting your answer code into the console on this page and using `document.body` as a target should show a list of over 50 attributes, including things like `contentEditable`, `contextMenu`, `dir`, `style`, etc.
- This also needs to work cross-browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could something like this be what you're looking for?

It looks like a DOM element object stores empty keys for all possible attributes. Could you loop over these keys and store them in an array, then from there use something similar to filter out inherited attributes?

**HTML**

```
<svg id="blah"></svg>
```

**Javascript**

```
const blah = document.getElementById('blah')
let possibleKeys = []
for (let key in blah) {
  possibleKeys.push(key)
}
```

Here's a [JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/tariretofo/edit?html,js,console) ... it looks like it produces a list of all possible attributes but it would need some filtering.

See also this thread.
[How to list all element attributes in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867477/how-to-list-all-element-attributes-in-js)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give anything useful - only the attributes that already have values :-(

Comment: Really? Hmm... did you check out the JS Bin? when I ran it I got a huge long list of all possible values. Maybe it depends on the front-end framework being used. Is it pure Javascript?

Comment: It looks like it also works in JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1x0ssxrk/ but not the same in codepen https://codepen.io/jestann/pen/qpvoav/?editors=1012 so maybe it is an environment thing.

Comment: It works, you should try directly in your browser's console with some random ID in the current page's HTML @Rycochet

Comment: Ok, I've just re-checked, and this code actually does it (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) - I don't know how it managed to mess up before, but tested and working, and the jumping off place for what I need!

Comment: Does anybody here know why this does NOT work for the "orient" attribute of a `<marker>` element? and what others might be exceptional?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for that and I don't think a workaround is possible because when you change an attribute on a current DOM node, the browser is responsible for re-rendering and updating the webpage in a low-level way that is not exposed to the JavaScript context.

Also, keep in mind that any correctly formatted attribute is actually valid in the context of a DOM tree, even though it might not trigger any change at the rendering level or in the way the browser renders the page. Especially the `data-*` attributes.

There might be some vendor-specific API but that wouldn't be useful if you want cross-browser compatibility.

You need to hardcode it, sadly. Given that you specifically want the `SVGElement` attributes, maybe you can scrape the [W3's SVG standard document](//www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/attindex.html) to automatically create the list?

Edit: I made a snippet to easily scrape the values from the standard:

```
const uniq = arr => Array.from(new Set(arr))

const nameElements = document.querySelectorAll('table[summary="Alphabetic list of attributes"] .attr-name')
const arrNameElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(nameElements)
const svgAttributes = uniq(arrNameElements.map(el => el.innerText.replace(/\‘|\’/g, '')))
```

Just execute it on the [svg attributes page](//www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/attindex.html), by opening the dev console on the page and pasting in this code :)

Edit 2: I forgot the presentation attributes. I'll let you figure that one out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any one of these should work because they return a live HTMLCollection.

```
var svgElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName("someSvgClass")[0];
//assume someSvgClass is on svg element.
//var svgElement = window.document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
//var svgElement = window.document.getElementsByName("mySvg")[0];
//assume svg has this name.

var svgAttributes = svgElement.attributes;

for(let i=0; i<svgAttributes.length; i++) {
  console.log(svgAttributes[i]);
}
```

See the below documentation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) on `getElementsByTagName()`

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The subtree
>   underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element
>   itself. **The returned list is live, meaning that it updates itself with
>   the DOM tree automatically. Consequently, there is no need to call
>   several times Element.getElementsByTagName() with the same element and
>   arguments.**

The documentation for [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) , and [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) say the same thing; a live node list is returned. If you'd like to try it, I created [a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/41qj2o2x/3/).

You'll see that svgAttributes list is automatically updated upon clicking "Add Attribute" without re-executing any of those functions.

Comment: By the way, getElementById and querySelector also seem to work in Chrome. Howeer, the MDN documentation doesn't say anything about these methods returning live node or live nodes.

Comment: Again, this doesn't actually show possible attributes, only the ones that already exist. In addition, please make sure that example code on here is complete, in your inline example `svgAttributes` doesn't exist, then it gets used.

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood your request. I thought all future attributes meant you were setting the attributes in the future. It seems like what you want is a list of all valid attributes (on an element) regardless of being set or not. Correct?

Comment: Yep - it's why I specifically stated "all possible valid attributes", and that it's not a duplicate as the several other ones are specifically about current attributes.

Comment: It's a good question; I'm not sure. For what it's worth, I did find this if you use node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-element-attributes . Although it doesn't provide anything for svg. It's does list attributes of other elements.

Comment: Sadly that one does something similar to what I'm doing now with a hardcoded list (it's also Node rather than browser) - it parses https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html for them (so could be extended for SVG easily with https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) - I'm thinking this might be the only way with part of the build script updating a static file... :-/

Comment: (Just to note that the repo linked to actually crawls different URLs for different HTML versions, but I only linked to a single one in my comment)